# Laravel - How to change app domain into to the test?

Tags: laravel, ubuntu

I have used app domain on my laravel projects till today, but today mozilla starts open app domains with `https..

So I edited my laravel.app.conf file and changed Servername as laravel.test then restart my apache2

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

But this time local website doesn't open, it says server not found..  Did I something wrong ? Or am I need to do something else ?

Edit: Also I changed /etc/hosts file too

Answer (score 0):

I just restart pc and now it works (But I restarted apache ?)

Comment: yes, apache is restarted also if you restart your pc